# Groovy: Dynamically addings methods with a specific signature

Tags: java, dynamic, groovy

So, I need to dynamically create (or inject) methods into an object that have a specific return type and method signature, because a Java tool we're using will be finding this methods via Reflection and checks for `void` type. Method names will be determined at runtime.

Using metaClass. = { ... } however adds a closure which doesn't show up as a regular method (even if it can be used as one) and also has a return type.

I can't modify the method finding code, and it it not Groovy-aware.

I can't use methodMissing() or invokeMethod() because the method needs to actually exist. If I could overload class.getMethods() I think it would be possible, but I can't figure out how.

Is there any way to do this in Groovy?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? i.e., give some example code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [AST Transformations](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compile-time+Metaprogramming+-+AST+Transformations) to add the code at compile time, but it wont work on classes that you don't compile, so I'm guessing that probably wont work.

You could probably replace the object with a CGLIB based proxy. If you can be more specific about the code in question...

EDIT: A little more info. Groovy metaClass magic is not available in Java unless the Java code were to explicitly call `groovyClass.invokeMethod("someMethod",args);`. So there isn't a way to do what you're asking with MetaClasses. CGLIB maybe.